# How to disable underline of react-router-dom Link tag globaly?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I use Material UI, and I want to disable the underline of links in the entire project.  Iused to do this with below approach:

menu.js:

```
<Link to="/someWhere" className={classes.linkStyle}>
  <div className={classes.button}> someWhere </div>
</Link>
```

style:

```
linkStyle: {
    textDecoration: 'none',
},
```

But I want to set this style for my entire project. I searched in [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) document, and I came up with this:

index.js (main component) :

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides:{
        MuiLink:{
            root: {
                textDecoration: 'none'
            }
        },
    },
  });

const routing = (
    <Router>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
            <Route path="/deploy" component={Deploy}/>
        </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('header'))
```

It's not working. I also tried:

```
    overrides:{
        MuiLink:{
            underlineNone: true
        },
    },
```

and

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    textDecoration: 'none',
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default `props` instead of style.

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiLink: {
      underline: "none"
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit wonderful-albattani-x08x2]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one of the this ways:

1. [Create your own Link component](https://material-ui.com/ru/api/link/#props)

   ```
   import { Link as MuiLink } from '@material-ui/core'

   const Link = ({children}) => <MuiLink underline="none" > { children } </MuiLink>
   ```
2. [Anchor props value to component](https://material-ui.com/ru/customization/globals/#default-props)

   ```
   const theme = createMuiTheme({
     props: {
       MuiLink: {
         underline: 'none'
       }
     }
   })
   ```
3. [Overrides by CSS](https://material-ui.com/ru/styles/api/#stylesprovider)

   ```
    //App.js  
    import { Link, StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
    import "./link.css";

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <StylesProvider injectFirst>
          <Link>I am Link</Link>
        </StylesProvider>
      );
    }

    //link.css
    .MuiLink-root:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
   ```